# Adding intermediate layer to the loss function in deep learning keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I want to use custom loss function using intermediate layers for DNN model VAE in keras. I call the model function and then add the loss to the layers.

Error is:

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval
```

`model` gets compiled but causes the error during training

```
#Below is the code which causes error
#this returns the models (en,de, model) and layers (z_mean and #z_log_sigma)
en,de,model,z_mean,z_log_sigma = load_model(config)
#defining loss using intermediate layers returned
kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.mean(1 + z_log_sigma - K.square(z_mean) - 
                      K.exp(z_log_sigma), axis=-1)

model.add_loss(kl_loss)
model.compile( optimizer=optimizer)
#error is raised during training 
history = model.fit_generator(
                    genfun,
                    steps_per_epoch = display_interval,
                    epochs = 1,
                    shuffle=False,
                    verbose = 1
                ) #callbacks=[eval_map])
```

Comment: What does the model look like? The error is about the computation graph having non-differentiable operation.

Comment: VAE uses reparameterization trick to make the model differentiable. Specifically, you generate a random distribution from mean 0 and variance 1. You multiply this random variable to tf.exp(z_log_sigma) and  add z_mean to it. Please make sure that you are doing this instead of generating normal distribution with mean z_mean and variance exp(z_log_std) directly.

Comment: @Abhishek Yes, I already used the reparametrization trick in load_model function. There needs to be a wrapper around custom loss function and now it works fine.

Comment: here a simple solution to put intermediate layers in loss computation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454500/how-to-use-tensorflow-custom-loss-for-a-keras-model

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for designing custom loss layer.

```
en,de,model,z_mean,z_log_sigma = load_model(config)

def custom_loss_wrapper(z_mean=z_mean,z_log_sigma=z_log_sigma):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        xent_loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
        kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.mean(1 + z_log_sigma - K.square(z_mean) - 
                    K.exp(z_log_sigma), axis=-1)
        return  xent_loss+kl_loss
    return loss
model.compile( 
optimizer=optimizer,loss=custom_loss_wrapper(z_mean,z_log_sigma))
```